# Need a mechanism for solve "OutOfMemoryException" for handle big Millions of IEnumerable<data> using Linq Group by with order each inner group list

Tags: performance, linq, group-by, collections

I faced OutOfMemoryException for handle millions Of IEnumerable data collections.

Ex) (not runs because format only)

```
Var list = new List(…) // (Count=3 million)

Var result = list.groupby(g=> g.key)
.select(s=> 
    new CustomClass(
     s.OrderBy(o1 => o1.date)
     .ThenBy(o2 => o2.skey)));
```

I done various operations using this result.
Ex create to dictionary and added to collectionview then filter finally filtered data’s only display to the data grid with pagination facility(in wpf).

One time screen display occupy more than 1 GB. We runs in x86 architecture.
.net framework 4.6.2

With any second operation ex. Next search with read from db. “OutOfMemoryException”  will occur.

Could you please provide me any idea for solve this.

Comment: No miracle here, do not load everything from database. Apply filtering, grouping on `IQueryable`, which is provided by EF or other LINQ provider.

Comment: The `GroupBy` will cause instantiation of all the objects needed for `list`, but without seeing actual code, we can only speculate. Perhaps try using x64? Also, what LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?